# PYTHON Find out which port the device is connected to by product id or vendor id

Tags: python, serial-port, usb

How to find out which port (ex. /dev/ttyACM0 etc) is used by a device, knowing the Product ID and Vendor id, using python?

Comment: If you can do it from the command line, you can do it using Python with `Popen`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`lsport` example that comes with libusbp](https://github.com/pololu/libusbp/tree/master/examples/lsport) to do this.  That is a C++ program, so you would need to compile it to an executable and then call the executable from Python and parse the results.

Another idea (that only works on Linux) is that instead of using unstable names like `/dev/ttyACM0`, you should use the symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`.